# Limiting a JScrollPane's scroll range

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

I have a `JTextArea` wrapped in a `JScrollPane`, which I use to log my application's output. I'm using the default, plain font with a size of 9 for the text area, and the scroll pane's height is 48 px. This results in an even distribution of lines in the scroll pane view, but there's a problem: if you scroll all the way up or all the way down, this happens:

[image]

As you can see, the top line got cut off, which is why I'm wondering if there's a way to limit the scroll pane's scroll range so it, for example, can't reach the top or bottom 6 pixels. Alternative solutions are also welcome.

Comment: suspect something wrong with your layout (never-ever even _think_ "px")

Comment: @kleopatra Why so? My application isn't resizable, so going with hard coded values rather than arithmetically working them out from the JFrame's size is much easier.

Comment: because you (most probably, mere guessing without seeing any code) wouldn't have had the problem if you had used a suitable LayoutManager instead of hard-coding :-) Plus it will break for minor changes (f.i. font, LAF, screen resolution ...)

Comment: Keep in mind that what I'm hard-coding aren't component positions; it's their dimensions. Even if I did use a more suitable layout manager (I'm using a run-of-the-mill `FlowLayout`), component sizes and/or offsets would have to be defined _somewhere_. For a simple, compact application (500×250) that cannot be resized, I made the trade-off of hard-coding the components' dimensions, knowing what that entails.

With that being said, I'd love to hear what you think: is there a better / _easier_ way, what should I use and how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the margin (top/bottom) of your JTextArea by setting a custom Border using the method `setBorder` inherited from `JComponent`. The [documentation for `JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29) suggests the following:

> Although technically you can set the border on any object that
>   inherits from JComponent, the look and feel implementation of many
>   standard Swing components doesn't work well with user-set borders. In
>   general, when you want to set a border on a standard Swing component
>   other than JPanel or JLabel, we recommend that you put the component
>   in a JPanel and set the border on the JPanel.

That would yield the same result as limiting the scroll range, while being more straight forward.

**EDIT:**

OP reported that the following solution worked for him:

```
textAreaLog.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 6, 0, 6));
```

Comment: @StanislavL Call me Lucky Luke *pewpew* ;)

Comment: That did the trick — setting the top and bottom insets to 0 with `textAreaLog.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 6, 0, 6));` worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch, both of you!

Comment: @StanislavL way too hacky .. either on the area itself or on a containing parent, the bordersize is always hard-coded pixels. That'll blow in all but the exact same environment it was developed on (LAF, font, dpi ...)

Comment: @KonstantinĐ: I just added your solution to my answer

Comment: @kleopatra My be better to use public Insets getMargin() of JTextComponent and play with the top/bottom margin. Set them to 0

Answer (score 2):

Place the `JTextArea` in a `JPanel` with empty borders where top and bottom insets are 6 pixels?